# unable to show record using webservice

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

this code is working fine but not showing records. in alert if i am getting record from file its working fine.

```
$j().ready(function(){      

            var result =$j.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "webService address",
                  dataType :'json',
                  contentType:'application/json; charset =utf-8',
                  success:function(data)
                  {
                    $j.each(data, function(index,element){
                          alert("Successful here: "+element);

                          });
                  }
            }); 
            alert("result"+result);

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of *asynchronous* ...

First of all, jQuery get doesn't *return* the data, that needs to be handled by the callback (which is working as from your post)

```
var result = null;
$j(document).ready(function(){      
        $j.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "webService address",
              dataType :'json',
              contentType:'application/json; charset =utf-8',
              success:function(data)
              {
                result = data;
                $j.each(data, function(index,element){
                      alert("Successful here: "+element);

                      });
              }
        }); 
        alert("result"+result);

    });
```

This might not work as well since jQuery ajax is ***asynchronous*** and the alert may pop up while the GET is still reading data and not yet ready !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check Jquery ajax [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "webService address",
    dataType :'json',
    contentType:'application/json; charset =utf-8'
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

The javascript is not waiting AJAX to finish, it moves on. That is why its called asynchronous . If you need synchronous call, use `async: false`.